# How intrusive/problematic is the Solidshield DRM used by EA?

Tags: drm, need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

I'm quite wary of DRM, and usually choose not to buy any game that has it, unless I know that it generally works (such as Valve games on Steam). I'm eyeing Shift 2 Unleashed though, and would like to know if the Solidshield DRM they use is likely to cause any problems, or if it's smooth sailing after activating.

Answer (score 4):

The DRM limits the game to 5 lifetime different machine installs (e.g. install on up to 5 different machines simultaneously. Uninstall one of these, and you should be able to reinstall on yet another machine). Note that you can effectively "lose" one of these installs by losing a hard drive, re-imaging, etc. without uninstalling first.

Comment: Source, please.